# Ansible cannot find the template dir

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am facing a very strange bug using Ansible.
I have a basic script using jinja templating.
My script is located inside a directory called junos.
I have specified that my templates will be located inside a directory called templates
Find here the script:

```
    ---
- name : Load and commit the config
  hosts: access_sw
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.6
  roles:
    - Juniper.junos
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name : "Load config from local file and commit"
      juniper_junos_config:
        load: "merge"
        template:
          src: "./templates/intf.j2"
          dest: "./build_conf/{{ inventory_hostname }}/intf.cfg"
        vars:
          host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        format: "set"
      register: response
```

We can see the file exists:

```
(prompt)--> ls ./templates/intf.j2
    ./templates/intf.j2
```

And ansible react saying it cannot find the template file:

```
    ansible-playbook --connection local -vvv -i junos_hosts.yml junos_sendconfig.yml
ansible-playbook 2.10.3
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:34:55) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
No config file found; using defaults
host_list declined parsing /home/jpbz7878/Programming/Ansible/junos/junos_hosts.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/jpbz7878/Programming/Ansible/junos/junos_hosts.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Skipping empty key (Remote-PE) in group (remote_pe)
Parsed /home/jpbz7878/Programming/Ansible/junos/junos_hosts.yml inventory source with yaml plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: junos_sendconfig.yml **********************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in junos_sendconfig.yml

PLAY [Load and commit the config] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [Load config from local file and commit] *******************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/jpbz7878/Programming/Ansible/junos/junos_sendconfig.yml:12
<acc1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: jpbz7878
<acc1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~jpbz7878 && sleep 0'
<acc1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155="` echo /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155 `" ) && sleep 0'
<acc2> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: jpbz7878
<acc2> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~jpbz7878 && sleep 0'
<acc2> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346="` echo /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/roles/Juniper.junos/library/juniper_junos_config.py
<acc1> PUT /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-31411hu73ud51/tmpt2duaeb7 TO /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py
Using module file /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/roles/Juniper.junos/library/juniper_junos_config.py
<acc1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/ /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py && sleep 0'
<acc2> PUT /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-31411hu73ud51/tmpyv9dt8vx TO /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py
<acc2> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/ /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py && sleep 0'
<acc1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py && sleep 0'
<acc2> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py && sleep 0'
<acc2> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py", line 102, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.juniper_junos_config', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_mt06_8b2/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/juniper_junos_config.py", line 1148, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_mt06_8b2/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/juniper_junos_config.py", line 1054, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_mt06_8b2/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/juniper_junos_common.py", line 1660, in load_configuration
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/utils/config.py", line 557, in load
    template = self.dev.Template(path)
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/device.py", line 516, in Template
    return self._j2ldr.get_template(filename, parent, gvars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/device.py", line 73, in get_source
    raise jinja2.TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: {'src': './templates/intf.j2', 'dest': './build_conf/acc2/intf.cfg'}
fatal: [acc2]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6911237-31419-243034751392346/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.juniper_junos_config', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_mt06_8b2/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/juniper_junos_config.py\", line 1148, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_mt06_8b2/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/juniper_junos_config.py\", line 1054, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_mt06_8b2/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/juniper_junos_common.py\", line 1660, in load_configuration\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/utils/config.py\", line 557, in load\n    template = self.dev.Template(path)\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/device.py\", line 516, in Template\n    return self._j2ldr.get_template(filename, parent, gvars)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py\", line 830, in get_template\n    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py\", line 804, in _load_template\n    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py\", line 113, in load\n    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/device.py\", line 73, in get_source\n    raise jinja2.TemplateNotFound(template)\njinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: {'src': './templates/intf.j2', 'dest': './build_conf/acc2/intf.cfg'}\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
<acc1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py", line 102, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.juniper_junos_config', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_rjlq97ce/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/juniper_junos_config.py", line 1148, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_rjlq97ce/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/juniper_junos_config.py", line 1054, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_rjlq97ce/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/juniper_junos_common.py", line 1660, in load_configuration
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/utils/config.py", line 557, in load
    template = self.dev.Template(path)
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/device.py", line 516, in Template
    return self._j2ldr.get_template(filename, parent, gvars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/device.py", line 73, in get_source
    raise jinja2.TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: {'src': './templates/intf.j2', 'dest': './build_conf/acc1/intf.cfg'}
fatal: [acc1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604716352.6777682-31418-79718055491155/AnsiballZ_juniper_junos_config.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.juniper_junos_config', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_rjlq97ce/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/juniper_junos_config.py\", line 1148, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_rjlq97ce/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/juniper_junos_config.py\", line 1054, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload_rjlq97ce/ansible_juniper_junos_config_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/juniper_junos_common.py\", line 1660, in load_configuration\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/utils/config.py\", line 557, in load\n    template = self.dev.Template(path)\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/device.py\", line 516, in Template\n    return self._j2ldr.get_template(filename, parent, gvars)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py\", line 830, in get_template\n    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py\", line 804, in _load_template\n    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py\", line 113, in load\n    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)\n  File \"/home/jpbz7878/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jnpr/junos/device.py\", line 73, in get_source\n    raise jinja2.TemplateNotFound(template)\njinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: {'src': './templates/intf.j2', 'dest': './build_conf/acc1/intf.cfg'}\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
acc1                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
acc2                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Did anybody face this kind of issue?

If yes thanks for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the variable playbook_dir :

```
template: "{{ playbook_dir }}/templates/intf.j2"
```

A complete list of special variables you will find here:
[special variables link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)

Comment: i have changed my answer according to the documentation https://junos-ansible-modules.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/juniper_junos_config.html . There is written: The src, lines, template, and url options are mutually exclusive. So if you use template do not use src etc. good luck